# How to use div class text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

As of now I am able to retrive the alt text from an image but I am also trying to retrive the text from a div class to display depending on the image. This is the script I am using to retrive the alt text

> ```
>       var title = $i.attr( 'alt' );
>         $('#title').text( title );
> ```

Now how do I replace the .attr is it .div? I am new to javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dunno what jQuery calls it, but you'd ask for the div's innerText or innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do it, it depends on wether you want all the styles inside the div as well.

```
<div id="subject"><span>Hello</span> world!</div>​

var text = $('#subject').text(); //Will return only the text with #subject
var html = $('#subject').html(); //Will return all tags. eg <span></span>
```

[Fiddle demonstrating it working](http://jsfiddle.net/TqpgR/)

[Documentation on .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[Documentation on .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking is to be able to get and set the class of a div:

Get the class from your div:

```
var myClass = $('#title').attr('class');
```

Set the class (assuming you only want to have one class for the div)

```
$('#title').attr("class","someClassYouWantToSet");
```

Comment: She's wanting to get the text within a div.

Comment: "How to use div class text in javascript?" confusing question :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` this way:

```
var myTextDiv = document.getElementById('divID');
console.log(myTextDiv.innerHTML)
​
```

Or using jQuery:

```
console.log( $('divID').innerHTML )
```

See it live:
http://jsfiddle.net/scMXx/3/